# Translate Laravel route param

Tags: php, laravel, routes, localization

I'm using Laravel 5.6 and trying to sort out what's the best method to translate a route.

I use top level domain to sort the locale so

```
mydomain.pt -> locale pt
mydomain.es -> locale es
mydomain.com -> locale en
```

I created a middleware to handle this

```
class Language
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $url_array = explode('.', parse_url($request->url(), PHP_URL_HOST));
        $top_domain = end($url_array);

        if(!empty($top_domain)){
            App::setLocale($top_domain);
        }
    }
}
```

This is working fine and the translated strings within the respective files work when i switch domain.

However i want to be able, for SEO purposes, to have links like this

```
mydomain.pt/dynamic/perto-de-mim
mydomain.es/dynamic/cerca-de-mi
mydomain.com/dynamic/near-me
```

What's the best approach in laravel to get my route

```
Route::get('{category}/near-me/', 'ServicesController@nearMe');
```

To work with all the examples above?

Thank you

Comment: You could use a library like this: https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization to help you out and simplyfy things a bit.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that library assumes that you are using a prefix and not another approach like mine, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel allow you to provide [translation string](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization#defining-translation-strings) :

```
/resources
    /lang
        /en
            routes.json
        /es
            routes.json
```

In resources/lang/es/routes.json :

```
{
    "near-me": "cerca-de-mi"
}
```

And your route become :

```
Route::get('{category}/' . __('routes.near-me') . '/', 'ServicesController@nearMe');
```

You could see here the use of the Laravel helper method **__()** to retrieve the translation from the xx/routes.json files.

Comment: I already did that. It didn't work...for what it seems, because Middleware only sets the locale on after the route is called. Does this make sense? Because my code was exactly like yours

Comment: Have you try to apply the middleware on a group of routes englobing those routes ? Something like : Route::middleware('language')->group(function() { /* Your routes */ }); (You'll have to register a route middleware named 'language' first)

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but it still doesn't work... The ``var_dump(App::getLocale())`` on the route gives me the default locale everytime